# Strange hanging issue running a Kivy application through TeamViewer

Tags: python, kivy, teamviewer

I've written a Kivy application which is essentially a camera display with pan/tilt control buttons at the side. My camera widget extends the image widget in Kivy and runs multiple threads which process the image in opencv and returns a frame every 1/30 seconds.

This all works perfectly when tested. However when I try to test this on a clients machine via TeamViewer I get my GUI - except the video does not load (I get a default white box, which I think is Kivys placeholder). Bizarrely, the video will only load when I open task manager after running the application.

My theory is that this may be due to fullscreen applications conflicting with teamviewer, but I have tested on both `fullscreen=auto` and `fullscreen=fake`and the problem persists.

While my camera will start working after I open task manager, if I then click back onto my application and try to click a button or do anything, Teamviewer will pop up and say it can no longer capture this screen. Note that this does not happen before the camera is loaded, my buttons do nothing before the camera is loaded.